# How to compile mcrypt for OS X Mavericks 10.9

Tags: macos, mcrypt, mhash

I'm having a heck of a time trying to compile mcrypt for OS X Mavericks.  I need mcrypt for a website I'm helping develop.  I installed Mavericks and then command-line tools for XCode using:

```
xcode-select --install
```

That ran an installer.  Then I downloaded libmcrypt-2.5.8 and unzipped it.  I navigated into the directory and did:

```
./configure
```

I don't know what kind of output I should have gotten, but I didn't get any success message either.  Just a lot of command-line code.  It just stopped and the prompt returned.

Then I did:

```
make
```

I get a whole bunch of output with a lot of warnings.  The last lines of output are:

```
creating aestest
Making all in doc
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all-am'.
```

I had an issue with mhash, when I went down the wrong road with mcrypt instead of libmcrypt.  I think the error messages are from that.  But I don't know how to fix them.  I didn't get any errors when I did this on my Mac at home, but I didn't go down the road with mhash then.  Thoughts, anyone?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps not exactly an answer to your question, but I would suggest installing it through [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org) instead (basically a Mac alternative for apt-get). While of course it should still be possible to manually install mcrypt, but with ports it's as easy as typing `sudo ports install mcrypt` and everything will be handled for you, including updates and uninstallation if you would ever need to do that.